# Multiple similar buttons Vue/Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button, vuetify.js

I have a search bar that returns a data from an API query in the form of

Data: [[id, datafield1, datafield2],[id, datafield1, datafield2],...]

I want to add an on/off button to each row of the data. Each button should have an independent way of telling whether it's off or on. I will add more functionality to it later and I like the look, so I would like to stick with v-btn if possible.

The button logic is

```
<v-btn
    color="primary"
    variant="outlined"
    @click="trackBill"
    >{{ this.trackedBtnText }}</v-btn
>
```

The scripts are

```
<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({ bills: [], trackedBtnText: 'Track', tracked: false }),
    methods: {
        async showBills() {
            this.bills = await showBills(this.keywords);
        },
        trackBill() {
            this.tracked = !this.tracked;
            this.trackedBtnText = this.tracked ? 'Tracked' : 'Track';
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

What happens is when I click one button, the text on EVERY button changes. I would like some way of maintaining individual variables for each function. They're going to make API queries later in the development process based on the data they are getting, so it would be great if they could hold other data too.

Comment: You need an array of button texts. The reason this happens is that, the text is bind to a single source.

Comment: Awesome. Setting it to an empty array still has the same effect. Is there a good paradigm for creating and accessing data on that array

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to do something multiple times, work towards using `v-for`. Do not repeat more code than you have to.

Just put your configuration data into objects in an array. Include everything you need to define a button, i.e. a title, the state, CSS classes, data you need for your queries, etc:

```
      buttonData: [
        {title: 'Column 1', checked: false},
        {title: 'Column 2', checked: true},
        {title: 'Column 3', checked: false},
      ]
```

then you can use a `v-for` to draw the buttons:

```html
        <v-btn
          v-for="button in buttonData"
          :key="buttonData.title"
          @click="$event => button.checked = !button.checked"
        >
         {{ button.title + ' is ' + (button.checked ? 'on' : 'off') }}
        </v-btn>
```

You can then access the state of the buttons through the array.

Note that buttons aren't really meant to be used as toggle switches. You might want to to think about using [switches](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/switches/) or [checkboxes](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/checkboxes/) instead.

Here is a snippet (not sure if you are using Vue 2 or 3, so I picked 2, but it shouldn't matter)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data(){
    return {
      buttonData: [
        {title: 'Column 1', checked: false},
        {title: 'Column 2', checked: true},
        {title: 'Column 3', checked: false},
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-btn
          v-for="button in buttonData"
          :key="buttonData.title"
          :color="button.checked ? 'primary' : 'secondary'"
          class="ma-4"
          @click="$event => button.checked = !button.checked"
        >{{ button.title + ' is ' + (button.checked ? 'on' : 'off') }}</v-btn>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```